# How to organize frequent used files in texstudio?

Tags: texstudio, linux

I usually use many files at the same time, each from different path. To make it easier to organize, I would like to bookmark this frequent files. Something similar to office pin function you see in this image:

[image]

While textstudio doesn't seem to have this option, I tried to collect shortcuts of all `.tex` files in a folder lets say desktop.So in Ubuntu (Lubuntu to be precise), I made a shortcut of my `.tex` file on desktop. (Select the file in `PCManFM` and with menu `Edit -> Create link`)
The problem is that when I open a shortcut, texstudio opens a copy of the file which is located in desktop and doesn't pick up the files from origin linked to shortcut.

Do you have any suggestion to fix my problem?

Comment: I've edited a  symbolic link with TeXstudio and the original file (in another path of the same partition)  was changed as expected. I make the symbolic link in a terminal  with `ln -s file link`

Comment: It is strange because I use the same command but I still face the problem.

Comment: May I ask what is your linux version?

Comment: Tested with Linux Mint 18 with texstudio package  2.10.8+debian-1

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but maybe this could serve as a workaround:

`Texstudio` does allow to save so called `Session`s - basically this means that texstudio remembers all the files which were open and reopens all of them if you use `Restore Previous Session`. Depending on your workflow you could either make a session that includes all your frequently used files or individual sessions for all of them.

[image]